# Dynamically Select Template based on template id field passed in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I want to select a template for sending email based on the template id present in Data Extension. So for all the subscriber with template_id(field in Data extension) ='123' should be sent the email template with id=123.
Can this be achieved SSJS?
[image: I have added a image of template and id I am trying to refer]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't apply a template to an email with any of the SFMC APIs, SSJS included.

It's likely because of the named content areas in the existing template have to be mapped manually to the new template.

If you'd update your question with some more details about what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps we can suggest some alternatives.  There are lots of ways do conditional content in an email.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the content i have made using content builder. I want to send email to my subscriber using the template based email if template_id  mentioned in data extension matches the ID of template.

Comment: Like I said, there's no dynamically switching templates in SFMC.  But you can conditionally hide or show content within a single email using AMPScript. That content can be the entirety of the email, if needed.

Comment: Maybe consider filtering your data extension audience on the  template_id.  Then create a  email send for each template time and specify a unique filter audience for each.

Comment: @david i have used that technique only